To what extent is Daniel 5 historically accurate?
Daniel 5 is obviously a point of contention when it comes to Biblical historical accuracy as historical sources tell us there was no king of Babylon named Belshazzar and indeed there is no record of a Persian king named Darius the Mede?
Of course, any other insights unrelated to these points are welcome! :)

I think you need to read a modern history based on recent finds.

Daniel 5 and in particular v. 31, is indeed problematic, especially if compared to what is written in  Haggai 1:1. See my answer to the following Q:- https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/29283/how-can-we-understand-the-different-dates-in-haggai-daniel-about-king-darius/49416#49416 ... Although your Q. could do to be fleshed out a bit, you are at least aware that Daniel 5 (31) is contentious, so I'll help you out here with an upvote. If you like how I answered, maybe you can do the same for me.

The premise of the question isn't entirely wrong. There are indeed ancient sources telling us that Nabonidus, not Belshazzar, was the last king of Babylon. However, Babylonian documents have been found (you can go to the British Museum in London and see them for yourself) confirming that Belshazzar did indeed exist and ruled as regent in Babylon while Nabonidus was absent. This explains why Daniel was made the third ruler in the kingdom, and also why Jeremiah 53 foretells messengers riding to tell the king that Babylon has fallen. Not only is the Biblical account of Belshazzar accurate, his disappearance from the historical record within a fairly short time proves that the account was written at or very near the time of the events. Wikipedia (disclaimer: Wikipedia has a heavy bias against Biblical historicity and I don't consider it a good source in general, but it shows that Belshazzar's existence is no longer disputed).
Regarding Darius the Mede the historical evidence is less clear. Berossus refers to a Darius of Media who ruled in parallel with Cyrus of Persia, but the original is lost and is preserved only in quotations by early Jewish and Christian authors. Harpocration states that the daric was named not after Darius the Great, as generally thought, but after "another more ancient king". Neither of those is conclusive proof and most skeptical scholars claim Darius the Mede didn't exist. But it's worth noting that skeptics claimed the same about Belshazzar for a long time. Our knowledge of ancient history is fairly patchy, absence of proof that someone existed is not proof that they didn't exist.

The bibilical record appears, from many such studies, to be more accurate than what is generally called 'history'. Up-voted +1.

@NigelJ I don't disagree. Secular history, like most secular science, can tell us a lot, but suffers from the same problems of overestimating its own knowledge and assuming it must be right now, despite all the times it's been wrong in the past. There's also a bias in how it treats the Bible, because of the assumption of a late date of authorship, but that assumption is circular reasoning and begging the question.

You got my attention, + 1. See my comment under the OP's question.

@OldeEnglish yes, I'm aware of the theories and incline to the view that Darius the Mede was in fact the same person as Cyaxeres II. Maybe someday they'll find proof. Thanks for the upvote :-)
