If Darius the Mede was a commander serving under Cyrus, why does Daniel 10 mention Cyrus while Daniel 9 mentions Darius?
The beginning of Daniel 10 says:

In the third year of Cyrus king of Persia... (Daniel 10:1)

While the beginning of Daniel 9 says:

In the first year of Darius son of Xerxes[a] (a Mede by descent)... (Daniel 9:1)

If Darius the Mede is a servant/commander of Cyrus the Great, why does Daniel not claim Cyrus to be the present king in verse 9?

Historically, the Achaemenid Empire founded by Cyrus (like its predecessors and successors, and several other empires) used the title "King of Kings" with the suggestion that they had vassals who were as good as ordinary kings, and the ruler of the empire was at an even higher level.

A possible answer to your Q. may be found in my answer to the following:- https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/29283/how-can-we-understand-the-different-dates-in-haggai-daniel-about-king-darius/49416#49416 ... Thanks for the Q., + 1.

There are two main approaches to this problem. One frankly admits that the Bible got it wrong. The other says that Darius the Mede was really a governor who served under Cyrus.
A note in the NABRE explains the first of these approaches:

Darius the Mede: unknown outside of the Book of Daniel. The Median kingdom did not exist at this time because it had already been
conquered by Cyrus the Persian. Apparently the author of Daniel is
following an apocalyptic view of history, linked to prophecy (cf. Is
13:17–19; Jer 51:11, 28–30), according to which the Medes formed the
second of four world kingdoms preceding the messianic times; see note
on Dn 2:36–45. The character of Darius the Mede has probably been
modeled on that of the Persian king Darius the Great (522–486 B.C.),
the second successor of Cyrus. The Persian Darius did appoint satraps
over his empire.

This explanation presumes that this section of Daniel was written long after the events described. Similar problems arise in the Book of Esther, which likewise (according to critical scholars) gets some important historical facts wrong.
The Encyclopedia of the Bible, on the other hand provides an explanation that supports the biblical account, while admitting that "Darius the Mede" was is not known to history:

It seems quite probable that Darius the Mede was another name for
Gubaru, the governor under Cyrus who appointed sub-governors in
Babylonia immediately after its conquest (“Nabonidus Chronicle,” ANET,
306; cf. Dan 6:1). This same Gubaru (not to be confused with Ugbaru,
governor of Gutium, the general under Cyrus who conquered Babylon and
died three weeks later, according to the Nabonidus Chronicle) is
frequently mentioned in cuneiform documents during the following
fourteen years as “Governor of Babylon and the Region Beyond the
River” (i.e., the entire Fertile Crescent). Gubaru thus ruled over the
vast and populous territories of Babylonia, Syria, Phoenicia, and
Pal., and his name was a final warning to criminals throughout this
area (cf. J. C. Whitcomb, Darius the Mede [1963], pp. 10-24). The fact
that he is called “king” in the sixth ch. of Daniel is not an
inaccuracy, even though he was a subordinate of Cyrus. Similarly,
Belshazzar was called “king,” even though he was second ruler of the
kingdom under Nabonidus (5:29).

The OP asks: "If Darius the Mede is a servant/commander of Cyrus the Great, why does Daniel not claim Cyrus to be the present king in verse 9?" The answer according to critical scholars is that this section the Book of Daniel is not meant to be understood as a factual account of history. According to pious scholarship, "king" could sometimes be used to address a governor.

Note that while there's no conclusive extrabiblical evidence, Darius the Mede is not quite as unknown to history as skeptical scholars like to claim - see the second part of the answer here.


Cyaxares II was a king of the Medes whose reign is described by the
Greek historian Xenophon. Some theories have equated this figure with
the "Darius the Mede" named in the Book of Daniel. He is not mentioned
in the histories of Herodotus or Ctesias, and many scholars doubt that
he actually existed. The question of his existence impacts on whether
the kingdom of the Medes merged peacefully with that of the Persians
in about 537 BC, as narrated by Xenophon (8.6.22, 8.7.1), or was
subjugated in the rebellion of the Persians against Cyrus' grandfather
in 559 BC, a date derived from Herodotus (1.214) and almost
universally accepted by current scholarship.
According to Xenophon's Cyropaedia (1.5.2), Cyaxares II became king
after Astyages to the throne of the Median Empire, and he was also the
brother of Mandane, Cyrus the Great's mother (1.2.1, 1.4.7). He
describes the Persian, Cyrus II/The Great, as leading the campaign to
conquer Babylon in 539 BC, while his uncle, Cyaxares II, remained in
Ecbatana. Cyaxares II was by then an old man, and because Cyrus II/The
Great was in command of the campaign, the army came to regard Cyrus
the Great as king. After Cyrus II/The Great invited Cyaxares (II) to a
palace he had prepared for him in Babylon, Cyaxares (II) granted him
his daughter (Cyrus II/The Great's first cousin) in marriage, with the
Median kingdom as her dowry. On the assumption that Cyaxares II is
Darius the Mede, it is claimed that he nominally reigned from Babylon
as head of the Medo-Persian empire for two years until his death, the
real power being Cyrus II/The Great's. Upon the death of Cyaxares II,
the empire passed peaceably to Cyrus II/The Great.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyaxares_II

Identifying Darius the Mede as Cyaxares II has been most recently (and
most thoroughly) proposed by Steven Anderson in his 2014 dissertation.
However, this viewpoint is not new, and was the standard Jewish and
Christian interpretation from Josephus and Jerome, until the 1870s.
However, scholarship of the last 150 years has cast doubt on this
viewpoint.
Many scholars identify Astyages as the last king of the Median
dynasty. According to the Nabonidus Chronicle, Astyages waged war
against Cyrus but was betrayed by his army and delivered over to Cyrus
in the year 550 BC. Thus, according to the Nabonidus Chronicle, Cyrus
took control of Media in 550 BC. This narrative is largely supported
by Herodotus, the ancient Greek historian.
However, if we consult Xenophon, a Greek historian just after
Herodotus, we are told a different history—a history of Cyrus ruling
Persia while in a strong alliance with Cyaxares II, the son of
Astyages. According to Xenophon, the Median dynasty extended past
Astyages through Cyaxares II, and when Cyaxares II died (2 years after
Babylon fell), the Median kingdom peacefully passed to Cyrus (537 BC).
Although you can read Stephen Anderson’s post for a thorough
discussion of this position, for the sake of brevity, I will summarize
four of Anderson’s arguments.

The Behistun inscription states that two men of Median descent
launched separate rebellions during the time of Darius the Great,
falsely claiming to be of the lineage of Cyaxares. This would only
make sense if Cyaxares were the last Median king. Otherwise, the claim
would likely relate to being descendants of Astyages (if he was indeed
the last king).

Herodotus and Xenophon agree that the daughter of Astyages, Mandane,
was the mother of Cyrus, an obvious marriage alliance between Persia
and Media. This is strong evidence for viewing Persia and Media as
being in some sort of strong alliance during the time of Cyrus.

The Harran Stele mentions a “king in the land of the Medes” during
Nabonidus’ 10th year (546/5 BC). This mention of a king of the Medes
along with the king of Egypt provides a date for the continuation of
the Median empire after the time of Cyrus’ supposed conquest as
described by Herodotus and the Nabonidus Chronicle.

A Greek playwright, Aeschylus, who dates prior to Herodotus, describes
two kings who preceded Cyrus as rulers of Medo-Persia. Although he
does not name them, he describes the first as the one who founded the
dynasty, and the second as being in power when Babylon fell (539 BC).
Aeschylus lists Cyrus as the successor of the second king. So, for
Aeschylus, Cyrus takes over the Medo-Persian empire after Babylon
falls.



https://petergoeman.com/darius-the-mede-as-cyaxares-ii-the-last-king-of-media/
https://truthonlybible.com/2016/01/08/darius-the-mede-a-solution-to-his-identity/
